# How to sort lightning-datable by url label

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

See this [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/MJpRRP4mz/1/edit) for an example.

The table gets sortedBy a url, rather than label. I guess I could try to hardcode something or name my fields in a way that's easy to drop url suffix, but it's a bit dirty.

Note `event.detail` doesn't have a `fieldLabel` property, just `fieldName`.

Is there some more elegant solution? Feels like datatable should have built in sorting function that's controlled declaratively, but that's topic for another discussion :)

Edit: For now my fix is

```
const dataField = column && column.typeAttributes && column.typeAttributes.label
    && column.typeAttributes.label.fieldName || sortedBy
cloneData.sort(this.sortBy(dataField, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add a custom attribute and use that for sorting purposes:

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name', sortBy: 'name' },
    {
        label: 'Age',
        fieldName: 'ageUrl',
        sortBy: 'age',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: {fieldName: 'age'},
        },
        type: 'url',
        sortable: true,
        cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },
    }
];
```

---

```
onHandleSort(event) {
    const { fieldName: sortedBy, sortDirection } = event.detail;
    const cloneData = [...this.data];
    const sortFieldName = this.columns.find(field=>sortedBy===field.fieldName).sortBy;
    cloneData.sort(this.sortBy(sortFieldName, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1));
    this.data = cloneData;
    this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
    this.sortedBy = sortedBy;
}
```

This trades a small extra setup (sortBy) to gain the ability to sort by whatever attribute you want, even a hidden value in a completely different field.